# Why can these two suspend function run without launch or aync in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning Coroutines of Kotlin, I run the *Code A* and get the *Result A*.

1: I'm very strange why the two suspend function both `doJob1()` and `doJob2()` can run without `launch` or `aync`. You know, a normal case is just like *Code 1*.

2: I think the *Result B* will be expect if *Code A* can run. Because the code `delay(3000L)` in `doJob1()` is 3s, so `doJob2()` will run first.

**Code A**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = doJob1()
        val two = doJob2()
        println("[testSequential] Result ${one + two}")
    }
    println("[testSequential] Completed in $time ms")   
}


suspend fun doJob1(): Int {
    println("Job1 Doing")
    delay(3000L) 
    println("Job1 Done")
    return 10
}

suspend fun doJob2(): Int {
    println("Job2 Doing")
    delay(1000L) 
    println("Job2 Done")
    return 20
}
```

**Result A**

```
Job1 Doing
Job1 Done
Job2 Doing
Job2 Done
[testSequential] Result 30
[testSequential] Completed in 4011 ms
```

**Result B**

```
Job1 Doing
Job2 Doing
Job2 Done
Job1 Done
[testSequential] Result 30
[testSequential] Completed in 4011 ms
```

**Code 1**

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch { doWorld() }  // It use launch
    println("Hello,")
}


suspend fun doWorld() {
    delay(1000L)
    println("World!")
}
```

Comment: 1. A suspending function can only be called from another suspending function or inside of a coroutine, and that's exactly what you're doing calling both functions inside the `runBlocking` block. 2. All the code inside `runBlocking` block will be executed sequentially unless you start another coroutine with `launch` or `async` inside of it to run something else concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runBlocking` starts a coroutine, so you can call suspend functions from within its block.

Your code calls `doJob1()` and `doJob2()` in sequence, so they are run in that sequence. If you want them to run simultaneously, you need to start new coroutines using `async` or `launch` to start each of them.